# Python 'latin-1' codec can't encode character - How to ignore characters?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Here is the gist of my code.  It's trying to get some text from an old website.  It's not mine, so I can't change the source.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("https://mattgemmell.com/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/")
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
article = soup.find_all('article')[0]
text = article.find_all('p')[1].text 
print(text)
```

Gives this:

'If youâ\x80\x99re a developer of either Mac or iOS apps that use networking, thereâ\x80\x99s a new feature in the Developer Tools for Mac OS X 10.7 â\x80\x9cLionâ\x80\x9d (read my review of it at The Guardian) which will be useful to you. This brief article describes how it works.'

I can use this to convert parts like â\x80\x99:

```
converted_text = bytes(text, 'latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

Actually works.

But if you get a different part of the text:

```
text = article.find_all('p')[8].text
```

Gives me:

'\n← Find Patterns in text on Lion\nUsing Spaces on OS X Lion →\n'

And using `bytes(text, 'latin-1')` gives me:

'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2190' in position 1: ordinal not in range(256)

I assume it's the arrows? How can I make it so all non latin characters are automatically ignored and discarded.

Any ideas would be most helpful!

Comment: Why are you encoding into latin-1 and then decoding with utf-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to ignore these characters. They are a symptom that the data you received has been decoded using the wrong character encoding. In your case `requests` has incorrectly guessed that the encoding is `latin-1`. The real encoding is `utf-8` and is specified in a `<meta>` tag in the HTML response. `requests` is a library for working with HTTP, it doesn't know about HTML. Since the `Content-Type` header doesn't specify the encoding `requests` resorted to guessing the encoding. `BeautifulSoup`, however, is a library for working with HTML and it is very good at detecting encodings. As such, you want to get the raw bytes from the response and pass this to `BeautifulSoup`. ie.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("https://mattgemmell.com/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/")
data = response.content # we now get `content` rather than `text`
assert type(data) is bytes
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
article = soup.find_all('article')[0]
text = article.find_all('p')[1].text 
print(text)

assert type(text) is str
assert 'Mac OS X 10.7 “Lion”' in text
```

Comment: I've added the full context of my problem so I can make sure I apply the fix at the right place.  My understanding is that beautiful soup is supposed to find the right encoding for you, and works for the most part except but on all webpages I'm trying to scrape.

Comment: @Frankie Made an edit. It's a simple change. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation and context, trying to make sure I do it right.

Answer (score 1):

Use the third argument to `bytes` to tell it how to handle errors:

```
converted_text = bytes(text, 'latin-1', 'ignore')
                                         ^^^^^^
```

You'll lose the arrows but otherwise everything's intact:

```
>>> text = '\n← Find Patterns in text on Lion\nUsing Spaces on OS X Lion →\n'
>>> converted_text = bytes(text, 'latin-1', 'ignore')
>>> converted_text
'\n Find Patterns in text on Lion\nUsing Spaces on OS X Lion \n'
```

Here's more info about the argument from the docs - https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html:

> The errors argument specifies the response when the input string can’t be converted according to the encoding’s rules. Legal values for this argument are 'strict' (raise a UnicodeDecodeError exception), 'replace' (use U+FFFD, REPLACEMENT CHARACTER), or 'ignore' (just leave the character out of the Unicode result).

Comment: This was helpful to know too.